# How do I use "don't be the one" in sentence?

Tags: sentence-construction, phrase-usage, sentence-meaning

Can I use in this way:

For example I'm advising a girl:

> People say girls are mean. Well don't be the one.

Is this correct? Or should I write "... Well don't be the mean girl"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither of these is idiomatic English.

In "Don't be the one", *the* tells your hearer that you are referring to a specific entity which has already been identified, or which you immediately define (for instance "Don't be the one who tells him"). She searches the discourse<sup>†</sup> to find *which* one you mean. In your pair of sentences there is no such entity, so *the* has no clearly identifiable referent.

"Don't be the mean girl" has the same problem. Again, *the* has no prior referent; and in English syntax an attributive modifier like ***mean*** girl doesn't satisfy the 'immediate definition' requirement. It 
*narrows* the reference—it sets your hearer looking for a *mean girl* rather than just any girl—but she's still looking for a specific mean girl.

So you don't want to use *the*; you want something *indefinite*.

- Bare *one* can be an indefinite pronoun, and "Don't be one (of them)", with no *the*, is marginally possible. But now the referent of *them* is unclear—do you mean "Don't be one of those people who say such things" or "Don't be one of those mean girls?"
- An alternative is a noun phrase with *a/an*. "Don't be **a** mean girl" is acceptable English, though in practise we'd probably emphasize the contrast between your hearer and those other girls by adding an emphatic *you*: "Don't **you** be a mean girl".

I invite you to consider, however, whether you want a nominal at all—what you're really talking about is the adjective complement, *mean*.

> Don't be mean.

What it seems you're trying to do is express that *mean* indirectly, by reference, through an expression which *refers* to it without echoing it;what we could call a 'pro-adjective', in the same sense that *one* and *they* are pro-nouns. In some contexts *so* can act as a pro-adjective ("Do not be so"); but that's very stiff and archaic, even in the most formal register. I suggest

> People say girls are mean. Don't you be like that.

---

<sup>†</sup> <sub>Or, more remotely, the knowledge of the world which both of you share: in the US, if you speak of *the president* your hearer will know that you mean Barack Obama. But this doesn't come into play in the circumstances you describe.</sub>

Comment: _in the US, if you speak of the president your hearer will know that you mean Barack Obama_  Oops. _Not_ William McKinley? ... All these years, man ... No wonder people think I'm weird.

Comment: Can you say *don't be so*? Or is it wrong?

Comment: @Subjunctive It's not wrong -- it's just not colloquial, and hasn't been since about the 17th century.

Answer (score 0):

I think the phrase you are looking for is

> People say girls are mean. **Don't be one of them.**
>   People say girls are mean. **Don't be like that**.

Meaning **don't fall into that category**.

The phrase

> Don't **be the one**

means literally don't be **that person**

> People say girls are mean. **Don't be the one** that breaks his heart.

Don't be the person that hurts him.

You could also say

> There are **nice** girls and there are **mean** girls, **don't be the mean girl**